# Resizing Background Images Using Media Queries Working for Webpage but not Email

Tags: image, email, text, background, fluid-layout

I am working on creating a responsive email template for a client.  I'm trying to get text to appear over an image, so I am attempting to create a responsive email that will display text over a fluid background image (I know...background images, emails, not a good combo, but I'm going for it).

I am able to get the code to work perfectly on a webpage (see here:  http://testwes.site90.com/NaerbyggEmailTemplateTestStylingv3.html ) however, when I send a test email (via Mailchimp) it seems the media queries are not picking up to change the background image, so the main background image (the picture of the house, paint, green etc.) does not change size, though the rest of my media query requests are working fine (text adjusting, icons moving around, even my header logo img resizes (not a background image of course).  You can see an example of the code after the email is sent here: (http://us7.campaign-archive1.com/?u=9be35a6a6ef5bf6014d5f59fe&id=ac4b24cd76).

I am really looking for any way to incorporate editable text over a fluid image for email, and I figured I'd give background images a shot.  If anyone has any advice for resizing background images via media queries for email, please help!

Thanks, 
Wes

Comment: Which email client are you testing in?  If you look at the attached list, you can see specifically which property you are trying to use will not work. Make sure your email looks ok with the background turned off.
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/